# SQL Where to filter on Nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Insert Into tblX (a,b,c)
Select x as a, y as b
   (select top 1 whatever from tblZ as z where z.aID  = y.aID order by z.s desc) as c
from tblY as y
where y.foo = 'bar'
AND c <> NULL
```

The problem is that last line. 
It tells me that c is an invalid column name. using y.c as well, to the same result.
I need to not inset rows where that giant inner query is null, because tblX cannot accept nulls there. I feel like I should be able to filter on that column, but I can't quite get the syntax right.

Comment: Edited statement to better show purpose. Y and Z both have a reference to A. A has many Z and many Y. I am creating and populating a new table to make Y a child of Z. I am adding all existing Y to the first Z of its associated A, but if A has no Z's I just ignore the Ys.

Comment: Thats really confusing using just letters, huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working is double nesting the query.

```
Insert Into tblX (a,b,c)
  Select a,b,c from
    (select x as a,
           y as b,
     (select top 1 whatever from tblZ as z where z.aID  = y.aID order by z.s desc) as c
      from tblY as y where y.foo = 'bar') as foobar
  Where c IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to double-nest this query.

Also, depends on your DBMS, but you should be checking `C IS NOT NULL`

You are using two tables without a join.  If you tell us what you are trying to achieve, we can help better.

Comment: hmmm. Not too sure what that means. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: @CaptnCraig: RE: `"Works like a charm. Thank you!"`        Is this question answered or not?

Comment: It was answered, but then edited the solution away. If you could put it back I would accept.

Comment: @CaptnCraig: Interesting.  This answer doesn't show as edited (Raj More might have changed it within a minute or two of 1st posting), so it can't be put back.   It's still correct within the level of detail of the question.   Mark it answered and/or post the solution that works as your own answer.